# Jquery date string not functional in Safari/Firefox, okay in Chrome

Tags: jquery, firefox, safari

I can't seem to figure out why this following does not display the date inside a span when using Safari 6.0.4 or Firefox 20 on the Mac (haven't tested Windows yet).

HTML:

```
<h1>Some Text <span id="dt"></span></h1>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var day = d.getDate();
var TodaysDate = month + '/' + day + '/' +  d.getFullYear() + '-';
var tDate = new Date(TodaysDate).toUTCString();
var dt = tDate.slice(0, - 12);
//The Date string
$('#dt').text(dt);

});
```

I've tried replacing `$('#dt').text(dt);` with `$('#dt').html(dt);` and there was no change.

This fills the `#dt` span with the date. It works fine in Chrome, but displays nothing in Firefox and Safari.

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/5yBRm/4/)

Any insight wold be appreciate.

Comment: "Does not work" is _never_ a sufficient problem description. Why aren't you using the `Date` constructor which accepts separate year, month, and day arguments?

Comment: Fari enough. Sorry I should have explained that the date was not appearing. As for not using a different date constructor... I'm not that educated and was trying the best I could.

Comment: You can easily educate yourself by reading some documentation `:)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax

Comment: I'm aware that there is documentation. Would love the time to review, understand, and be able to implement things exactly as I want. But time does not permit. I needed a fast solution, to be refined later. I traditionally use PHP date functions and this is the first time I've needed to use javascript dates without jQuery datepicker. Thanks for linking to the obvious rather than actually assisting ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the `-` in:

```
var TodaysDate = month + '/' + day + '/' +  d.getFullYear() + '-';
```

That generates `5/6/2013-` which apparently only Chrome tolerates.

Change it to:

```
var TodaysDate = month + '/' + day + '/' + d.getFullYear();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/5yBRm/5/)**

Comment: please explain why this breaks it.

Comment: I suppose some `new Date()` implementations are more tolerant than others.

Comment: dont check him off until he explains himself :)

Comment: @Pinch - a) I don't recall anyone electing you as the SO gatekeeper. The OP can do as they wish and b) my explanation is that Chrome is more tolerant of a malformed date string than the other browsers.

Comment: whow...missed that elephant.

Comment: Oh I thought Pinch was eluding to something else. Yes removing the trailing dash fixes it. Will accept when I'm able to.

Comment: @J08691 +1 for putting up with me.

Answer (score 1):

Already answered, but if you're open to the idea of using small helper libraries, I really like this one:
http://momentjs.com/

It's a very nice wrapper. To get the current date/time just do this:

```
var now = moment();
```

To format it to a UTC string, just do this:

```
now.utc().format(<your params>)
```

Comment: Thanks. Will absolutely look for future use. But this particular page is a single page and I don't want to load it with too many libraries. Traditionally I'd use PHP date functions, but I'm trying to stick to client-side for this, which is where this issue popped up.